# Thunderbird: how to get back the folder view switching arrows?

Tags: thunderbird

The folder pane in Thunderbird *used to* have a left and right arrow that allowed switching between the folders displayed. However, since a week or so, the arrows are gone (update? miss-clicked something?)

As I use them several times a day: **how can I get the arrows back?**  I have Thunderbird 8.0.

[image: Thunderbird arrows before/after]

Note: I know, switching is also accessible via the menu bar > View > Folders, but this is too much clicks for me.

Comment: There is an add-on at Mozzila called "FOLDER PANE VIEW SWITCHER 1.7" that restores the function for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a 'feature' of Thunderbird 8 ([from the 8.0 release notes](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/8.0/releasenotes/)).

> The latest version of Thunderbird has the following changes:
>
> - Folder switching pane widget has been removed, can be added back
>     with the [Folder Pane View Switcher Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/folder-pane-view-switcher/)

Great, well done, Mozilla :-| From the add-on reviews seems I am not alone in thinking that Mozilla is taking some strange (and wrong) decisions here.